# Consuming SSIS Data Profile XML

Tags: ssis, xsd, xml-serialization

I am attempting to read the output of an SSIS Data Profile task into an MVC app. To work out the kinks, I wrote a small console app to test the parsing of the xml file.

I used the following link:

http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/DataDebugger/DataProfile.xsd

to download the .XSD file that should describe the .XML file that was generated in the Data Profile output file.

I then ran xsd.exe to create a C# class to include in my console app.

Following is my very simple test code:

```
        XmlSerializer xser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataProfile));
        DataProfile dProf = xser.Deserialize(new FileStream(@"D:\InputFiles\ProfilerDataCVD.XML", FileMode.Open)) as DataProfile;

        if (dProf != null)
        {
            var profs = dProf.DataProfileOutput.Profiles;

            foreach (ColumnValueDistributionProfileType c in profs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Column Name: {0}, RowCount: {1}, Distinct Values: {2}", c.Column.Name, c.Table.RowCount, c.NumberOfDistinctValues));
            }
        }
```

In that code, "dProf" is never NULL, but always empty. Any assistance at getting data in dProf would possibly save a life, because I am about to jump off of a cliff trying to figure this out!

If there is some obvious XML thing that I am missing, I will be the first to admit that this is not my strongest suit. Feel free to chastise me at will as long as you tell me how to make this return data.

Answer (score 0):

Regrettably, no one has been able to answer this question. And I would still really like to understand why something so simple does not work.

In the meantime, anyone else struggling with the same issue should check out the following link on MSDN forums for an alternative way of doing the same thing.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/a282bb60-c099-4656-bf71-52ddc6153c28

I implemented it yesterday in just a few minutes and it works great.